# NPM Error when installing napi-js or @adonis/cli

Tags: node.js, npm, hapi.js, hapi, adonis.js

I am getting an error when i tried to install adonis cli or hapi-js. It is difficult to tell why am I getting this error on my system, maybe you guys have a hit or an idea.

```
npm --version
6.8.0

node --version
v10.14.2
```

This is the error when installing hapi-js
sudo npm i -g  napi-js

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@10.14.2 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to sourcecompile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/lib'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/napi-js/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ napi-js@3.0.5
added 252 packages from 189 contributors in 12.164s
```

I get something similar when doing:
sudo npm i -g @adonisjs/cli

Now, notice how the package still gets install on my machine. Any clues?

Comment: this might be because of persmission issues. try your command with sudo or refer her https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this same error.

I solved it with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g @adonisjs/cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```